# Freeze NFT on Solana

Tags: solana-program, web3.js, rust, nft

Can I freeze an NFT in another wallet? For example, if I mint an NFT and send it to another wallet, can I freeze it so the recipient can't send the NFT to another wallet unless I choose to unfreeze it? Does Metaplex offer this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm pretty sure you can freeze token accounts if that was made possible when creating the tokens. So i would say that you can freeze an nft in another wallet

**Edit:** i think both other answers are false. You **CAN** freeze token accounts, and there is **no link with being the delegate**.

Check this: https://spl.solana.com/token#freezing-accounts

Delegation let you control over a token accounts (in order to move some tokens for example).

In order to freeze a token account, you should have access to the freeze authority keypair. It's not linked with metaplex, it's linked with Solana SPL token program (see link above).

Comment: Hi @Effe2, thanks for your reply. Let's suppose I freeze an NFT that is in another wallet since my wallet has freeze authority. Can I also unfreeze the NFT after a certain time? Because I've noticed that once I freeze something the token then I never unfreeze it.

Comment: yes you can unfreeze the token account which holds the nft, check the link i sent you, it's written "Token instructions that include a frozen account will fail until the Account is thawed using the ThawAccount instruction.", so you have to check ThawAccount instruction to see how to unfreeze an account

Comment: Okay, that's perfect. thanks for your help.

Comment: @Effe2- How can I get any info on how to use the SPL program to freeze or unfreeze the account?

Comment: Metaplex provides two functions 'freezeDelegatedNft' and 'thawDelegatedNft'. are these functions work?

Comment: Yes, those functions will work if you're the delegate.

Answer (score 0):

You can freeze an NFT you are the delegate of. The wallet holding the NFT just needs to sign a transaction approving you as the delegate.

Here is the Developer Hub documentation for how to do it for both NFTs and pNFTs and an explanation for why you must be the Delegate.
https://developers.metaplex.com/token-metadata/lock

Comment: delegation and freezing are 2 different concepts, no link here IMO

Comment: The Master Edition account is the freeze authority and allows the delegate to freeze. So in this case they are the same.